# getChildHtml(' ', true, true) - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, local.xml

What does it mean these:

```
1. <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('child.name') ?> // get the child parent block

2. <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('') ?> //?

3. <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?> //?

4. <?php echo $this->getChildHtml(' ', false, true) ?> //?

5. <?php echo $this->getChildHtml(' ', false, false) ?> //?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter `$name` is a block name. With the second `$useCache` you can force to do NOT load block html from cache (even when block cache is enabled in admin config). This `$sorted` sets that child blocks are rendered according to the sorting order defined by `before` and `after` in layout.xml.

1. get child block by name from cache
2. get all children from cache
3. get all sorted children from cache
4. get all children w/o cache
5. get all sorted w/o cache

> Mage_Core_Block_Abstract

```
/**
 * Retrieve child block HTML
 *
 * @param   string $name
 * @param   boolean $useCache
 * @param   boolean $sorted
 * @return  string
 */
public function getChildHtml($name = '', $useCache = true, $sorted = false)
{
    if ($name === '') {
        if ($sorted) {
            $children = array();
            foreach ($this->getSortedChildren() as $childName) {
                $children[$childName] = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($childName);
            }
        } else {
            $children = $this->getChild();
        }
        $out = '';
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $out .= $this->_getChildHtml($child->getBlockAlias(), $useCache);
        }
        return $out;
    } else {
        return $this->_getChildHtml($name, $useCache);
    }
}

/**
 * Obtain sorted child blocks
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getSortedChildBlocks()
{
    $children = array();
    foreach ($this->getSortedChildren() as $childName) {
        $children[$childName] = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($childName);
    }
    return $children;
}

/**
 * Retrieve child block HTML
 *
 * @param   string $name
 * @param   boolean $useCache
 * @return  string
 */
protected function _getChildHtml($name, $useCache = true)
{
    if ($useCache && isset($this->_childrenHtmlCache[$name])) {
        return $this->_childrenHtmlCache[$name];
    }

    $child = $this->getChild($name);

    if (!$child) {
        $html = '';
    } else {
        $this->_beforeChildToHtml($name, $child);
        $html = $child->toHtml();
    }

    $this->_childrenHtmlCache[$name] = $html;
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `get all sorted children from cache` ? admitting that  we put this`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml(' ', false, true) ?>` or `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml(' ', false, false) ?>` what does it mean

Comment: Update my answer. :)