# getChildHtml() with empty string

Tags: blocks, magento-1.9.2.0

In `wrapper.phtml` there is this line of code:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true);
```

What happens in this case when `getChildHtml()` is called with an empty string? What block/code is it calling?

Comment: Magento version?

Comment: the version is 1.9.2.0

Answer (score 0):

> Mage_Core_Block_Abstract

```
/**
 * Retrieve child block HTML
 *
 * @param   string $name
 * @param   boolean $useCache
 * @param   boolean $sorted
 * @return  string
 */
public function getChildHtml($name = '', $useCache = true, $sorted = false)
{
    if ($name === '') {
        if ($sorted) {
            $children = array();
            foreach ($this->getSortedChildren() as $childName) {
                $children[$childName] = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($childName);
            }
        } else {
            $children = $this->getChild();
        }
        $out = '';
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $out .= $this->_getChildHtml($child->getBlockAlias(), $useCache);
        }
        return $out;
    } else {
        return $this->_getChildHtml($name, $useCache);
    }
}
```

**ALL cases:**

```
1. <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('child.name') ?> // get child block by name from cache

2. <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('') ?> // get all children from cache

3. <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?> // get all sorted children from cache

4. <?php echo $this->getChildHtml(' ', false, true) ?> // get all children w/o cache

5. <?php echo $this->getChildHtml(' ', false, false) ?> // get all sorted w/o cache
```

[Reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/174711/48355) **@sv3n**

Comment: If you copy answer of someone please give credit to actual person @Prince